Calculate the sum $\sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{\sin (\pi n)}{n}$
I would like to calculate the sum $\sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{\sin (\pi n)}{n}$. I know that $\sin n \pi =0$ $\forall n\neq 0$, so I obtain
$$ \sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{\sin (\pi n)}{n} = \frac{\sin(0)}{0} + \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin (\pi n)}{n}}_{=0}+ \underbrace{\sum_{n=-N}^{-1} \frac{\sin (\pi n)}{n}}_{=0}.
$$
the problem is $ \frac{\sin(0)}{0}$ because I know that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$  but how to justify conceptually the use of the limit in the sum?

$\sin(0)/0$ is not defined. Moreover, why are the two sums in RHS individually $0$? Their sum is $0$ because for each positive term there is a corresponding negative term to cancel it out. However, the sums, individually are not $0$.

@sudeep5221, not only each sum is zero, each term of each sum is zero, as $\sin(n\pi)=0$ if $n$ is integer.

You're right. My bad. Didn't spot that.

Much more interesting would be $\sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{\sin (x n)}{n}$
